# Looking for name of a double ended connector

Tags: game-design, custom-game-pieces

I'm building a board game that connects pieces together, like  a puzzle, but they can be flipped over, so I have found a picture of what I think would be a good connector piece, but I'm not sure what it would be called.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ACFAZCE]

A piece like this would help me connect my double sided pieces together in any configuration. What is this connector piece called?

Comment: If one side was attached, it would be a [sliding dovetail joint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetail_joint#Sliding_dovetail).

Comment: Deleted a pedantic back and forth.  @users - lets play nice, especially with new people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question would probably receive a better answer on [Woodworking SE](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/).

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_joint), as well as [Canadian Woodworking](https://www.canadianwoodworking.com/tipstechniques/butterfly-key), this is called a Dovetail key, Dutchman joint, or Butterfly joint. Another common name for it is a Bowtie joint/key. Below is the picture shown on Wikipedia:

[image]

Dovetail keys are used to hold together two boards or one board that has begun to split (to prevent further splitting). In [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/DLQkk-x5CeI?t=848), a woodworker further elaborates on its uses and also demonstrates how to make one.

Comment: Good find! The one caveat is that the woodworking context if I understand right this is a technique meant more for a snug, permanent join, and it implies this specific shape, as opposed to a more generic shape. So since the OP is making a board game with temporary connections and would likely be okay with some variety of shapes, this might not be a perfect analog. Still definitely useful for searching around, though.

Comment: @Jeformi is right, but these has been the most clear in helping me find something to make these with chipboard.

Comment: For future people, http://www.1stopsquare.com/punches/customlist.html, punch 730 makes this shape, but is small